# What is this proverb?

Tags: mandarin, phrase, idioms, phrase-request

I met someone who told me a proverb which in English read as follows:

> Wake up late and you lose the morning. Wake up early and you lose the
>   whole day.

She repeated it in Mandarin very quickly before I left, but if it helps the last word was 天.

Do you know this proverb?

Comment: I have never heard any similar ones, and it doesn't sound like Chinese proverb to me.

Comment: this  'proverb' seems to telling people the importance of having enough sleep. But Chinese generally believe "sleep early, get up early, your health will be great" . (早睡早起身體好) . So I don't think it is a Chinese proverb

Comment: @TangHo it seems to be more of a joke and less of a proverb, but still apparently a well-known one. It was definitely Chinese as well

Answer (score 6):

> (熬夜)晚起毀上午，早起(學習)傻一天

熬夜晚起毀上午
晚起毀上午
Getting up too late will lose a morning.

早起學習傻一天
早起傻一天
Getting up too early will have no spirit all day long.